# NEXTJS API routes not working in production mode, getting a 502 error

Tags: rest, next.js, vercel, webpack-production

## ISSUE

I am unable to fetch my API routes in production mode and receiving an error of

```
VM15:1 GET https://movies-words-ts-86xlkq6rp.vercel.app/api/movies/tt5052448/words 502

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 502
    at LYNF.e.exports (fcae4559c849ad3f0939b7cca63449d545e4627d.d32ee7ae9c5841de2d98.js:1)
    at Rn+g.e.exports (fcae4559c849ad3f0939b7cca63449d545e4627d.d32ee7ae9c5841de2d98.js:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.p.onreadystatechange (fcae4559c849ad3f0939b7cca63449d545e4627d.d32ee7ae9c5841de2d98.js:1)
```

Though everything works perfectly fine in development mode.

## File information

[api page](https://github.com/rohitmi0023/movies_words_ts/blob/master/pages/api/movies/%5BmovieId%5D/words.ts)

[next.config.js](https://github.com/rohitmi0023/movies_words_ts/blob/master/next.config.js)

code from where I am calling the route, [dict.tsx](https://github.com/rohitmi0023/movies_words_ts/blob/3c79ee53b185628a3cd6e96415c354ffa10d5494/pages/movies/%5BmovieId%5D/dict.tsx#L91)

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/15981 In my case I should have been getting a 413 Payload Too Large error but it's defaulting to 502 instead.